# CentOS not considering daylight saving on timezone

Tags: timezone, date

In Brazil, this year, the president decided we should not have daylight saving. And because of that my Centos 8 server is with the time wrong, I mean, when I use `date` the time shown is wrong by 1 hour. Usually, when I set my server I execute this:

```
ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Brazil/East /etc/localtime
```

The Brazil East timezone is now -3, but using the file above the timezone gets -2 (because for some reason it's wrongly believing we should have daylight saving this year, as it has always been).

So how do I fix this? Is there a way I can tell my server to update the zoneinfo files based on goverment decisions day by day? Lets supose the brazilian President today decides that we should get into DST tomorrow. Is there an international organization that provides those zone files updated according to local goverment decisions?

obs: I tried `nano` the file /usr/share/zoneinfo/Brazil/East however weird chars appears on the screen so I gave up editing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Brazil's DST change was [included in TZ version 2019b](http://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz-announce/2019-July/000056.html).

<strike>Running `yum update tzdata` should get you the newest version (which is actually `2019c`, but it includes the change you care about).</strike>

You can use `rpm -q tzdata` to check the version you have.

CentOS seems to be running behind on making these updates available - they still only offer 2019a. See https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=72416 for discussion and https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=16702 for the bug report

Comment: I executed "dnf update tzdata" and it said nothing was updated. So I think I am using the latest version and still the problem persists. When I executed `rpm -q tzdata` it returned "tzdata-2019a-1.el8.noarch".

Comment: do you know how do I make my tzdata use the 2019c file instead of the 2019a file? Cause no matter what I do, the 2019a file never gets updated!

Comment: @Samul I just updated my answer with a link to the CentOS forum. There are two workarounds described there.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 5):

Brazil no longer observing DST is in [tzdata-2019b](http://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz-announce/2019-July/000056.html) circa July. (ICANN, formerly IANA, is the maintainer compiling the changes.)

For some reason, I only find 2019a on the CentOS 8 mirrors. Consider raising the issue in a bug report or mailing list. Upstream [RHEL commits to a prompt tzdata release](https://access.redhat.com/articles/1187353).

Until this is updated, consider picking another city at the same offset, like [America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/argentina/buenos-aires). (Hopefully both do the sane thing and stay on no DST, but who knows...)

Comment: You suggestion of using Buenos Aires was great! I executed `rpm -q tzdata` and my server returned `tzdata-2019a-1.el8.noarch`. So I am using the `2019a` even after `dnf update --refresh` I am still using `2019a`. I will report as a bug as you said but if you have any other suggestion I would be glad to try!